# How to migrate data from SAP BW to S3/Redshift/BigQuery/... (Cloud storages / databases)

Tags: database-migration, data-warehouse, cloud-storage, sap-bw

What are the possibilities to migrate SAP BW to AWS/Azure/GCP Cloud (either to cloud storages or to cloud databases/DWHs)?

Disclaimer: I have never used SAP BW, only the cloud services.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to implement an ETL Tool (talend e.g.) and then connect to the SAPand then load the Data in certain periods (minutes wise to get the delta or maybe day wise).